# Modifying Apache site config broke site; restoring didn't fix

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wanted to setup a subdomain on my site to redirect to a referral link, and found online that **RedirectPermanent** is the way to do it. I neglected the Permanent part of it, and my first iteration didn't work. So I decided to just go back to how it was before, and now JavaScript files won't server (they 404, and not even going to the 404 page I created, just the default 404). As far as I can see, everything else is serving ok.

So here's my site config attempt:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName amazon.gamersplane.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://smile.amazon.com/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&linkCode=ur2&tag=gampla0e6-20&linkId=7RQR4I66XH6Z2U4B
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dtrpg.gamersplane.com
   RedirectPermanent / http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/browse.php?affiliate_id=739399
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@gamersplane.com
    ServerName gamersplane.com
    ServerAlias www.gamersplane.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/gamersplane
    <Directory /var/www/gamersplane/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gamersplane/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel notice

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/gamersplane/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The top two virtual hosts are the two new sections. The lower part is nearly exactly the same as it was before, except instead of www in the **ServerAlias**, it was *.

In my .htaccess, I'm using modrewrite to direct all non-image/js/css/etc requests to a dispatch file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 errors/401
ErrorDocument 403 errors/403
ErrorDocument 404 errors/404

Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oneRunScripts/
RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|ttff|svg|psd)$ dispatch.php
```